# A Question on Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis

The following is an exercise in Knapp's book, representation theory of Semisimple Groups.

For $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2-\{0\})$ with norm
$$\|f\|^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x,y)|^2 dx dy,$$
define $E_v:f\mapsto F_v$ by
$$
F_v(x,y)=\int_{0}^\infty f(tx,ty)t^{iv} d t.
$$
The image is a dense subspace of
$$
H_v^+\oplus H_v^-=\{F:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb C, F(tx,ty)=t^{-1-iv}F(x,y),\forall t>0\}$$
with norm
$$
\|F\|_v^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} |F(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)|^2 d\theta.
$$

Let $h(s)=e^sf(e^sx,e^sy)$, $-\infty<s<\infty$. 
By Fourier inversion formula and Plancherel formula,
establish
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\infty^\infty F_v(x,y)dv
$$
and
$$
\|f\|^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\|F_v\|_v^2 d v
$$
for $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2-\{0\})$.

The first one is easy to obtained by
$$
h(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{h}(\xi)d\xi.
$$
How to establish the second formula?